# How to pass an object from one activity to another on Android

Tags: java, android, object, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to work on sending an object of my *customer* class from one `Activity` and displaying it in another `Activity`.

The code for the customer class:

```
public class Customer {

    private String firstName, lastName, address;
    int age;

    public Customer(String fname, String lname, int age, String address) {

        firstName = fname;
        lastName = lname;
        age = age;
        address = address;
    }

    public String printValues() {

        String data = null;

        data = "First Name :" + firstName + " Last Name :" + lastName
        + " Age : " + age + " Address : " + address;

        return data;
    }
}
```

I want to send its object from one `Activity` to another and then display the data on the other `Activity`.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I used to set object to Pacelable or Serializable, but whenever I add other variables, I have to add it all to functions to get and set for Pacelable or Serializable. so I made DataCache to transfer between activities and fragments. https://github.com/kimkevin/AndroidDataCache It's super easy to transfer object.

Comment: I've created a wrapper TrackedReference<Any> that is parcelable and serializable without requiring marshaling (serializing or parcelizing) for the underlying type: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64944753/3405387

Comment: why don't you just use static variables and access it from other activity, without recreating it in memory and also sterilization of object may consume resources.

Answer (score 976, accepted):

One option could be letting your custom class implement the `Serializable` interface and then you can pass object instances in the intent extra using the `putExtra(Serializable..)` variant of the `Intent#putExtra()` method.

**Actual Code**:

In Your Custom Model/Object Class:

```
public class YourClass implements Serializable {
```

At other class where using the Custom Model/Class:

```
//To pass:
intent.putExtra("KEY_NAME", myObject);
```

myObject is of type "YourClass".
Then to retrieve from another activity, use getSerializableExtra
get the object using same Key name. And typecast to YourClass is needed:

```
// To retrieve object in second Activity
myObject = (YourClass) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("KEY_NAME");
```

Note: Make sure each nested class of your main custom class has implemented Serializable interface to avoid any serialization exceptions. For example:

```
class MainClass implements Serializable {
    
    public MainClass() {}

    public static class ChildClass implements Serializable {
         
        public ChildClass() {}
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a same situation, after I implement Serializable, do I have to do anything special in my class, do I have to implement some methods?

Comment: @OD: In my defense, I never said this was the best option; OP just asked for alternatives and I suggested one. 
Thanks anyways.

Comment: Why is Serializable not a good option?  It's a well-known interface, there's a good chance that peoples' classes may already implement it (ArrayList, for example, is already Serializable).  Why should you have to change your data objects to add extra code simply to pass them from one class to another?  That seems like a bad design.  I can imagine there may be some performance impact at some level, but I'd think that in 99% of cases, people are passing small amounts of data, and they won't care.  Simpler and portable is sometimes better, too.

Comment: I'll also add that as this question is not a general one, but a specific one (regarding the poster's Customer class), in this case performance should be insignificant with such a simple, tiny data object.

Comment: Quite the contrary, Parcelable is not advised as mechanism to pass object between activities, it's ment for IPC. So serializable is a good option, just use it sensibly...

Comment: @Sander: Is this answer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2139134/how-to-send-an-object-from-one-android-activity-to-another-using-intents/2141166#2141166) wrong then? He says that `Parcelable` **IS** specifically designed for that purpose (and much faster than `Serializable`). I am a confused.

Comment: @Slauma well as a matter of fact both do work, but Parcelable was initially created for use in IPC because the overhead when using Serializable. But for simple object transfer between activities it's not noticable and all the plumping involved using Parcelables ain't worth it IMO. They would not include the putSerializable method in the Bundles interface when the use of it is discouraged and to date it is not deprecated. So in my opinion, when your sure you don't need IPC use the Serializable interface, it's much easier. Avoid large object graphs, but same would be true van a Parcelable.

Comment: I would just like to add a real world example .. I was using serializable to pass a complex object between activities. Creating the intent was taking 200ms, and reading it in the receiving activity took 100+ms, after changing to parcelable it dropped to 6ms and 68ms respectively. So it's definitely worth using parcelable for speed

Comment: `Parcelable` might be good for speed, but it is complicated to implement. What if you have 8 objects you need to pass between activities, are you going to make each one `Parcelable`? It would make more sense to use `Serializable` instead. When you implement `Parcelable` you have to add a lot of code to the class, and order fields in a very specific manner; `Serializable` you don't. Ultimately, I think it comes down to how many objects you are passing and what you are trying to do.

Comment: `Serializable` is a standard Java interface. You simply mark a class Serializable by implenting the interface, and Java will automatically serialize it in certain situations.


`Parcelable` is an Android specific interface where you implement the serialization yourself. It was created to be far more efficient that Serializable, and to get around some problems with the default Java serialization scheme

Comment: if you are wondering why not Serializable: "The problem with this approach is that reflection is used and it is a slow process. This mechanism also tends to create a lot of temporary objects and cause quite a bit of garbage collection." from http://www.developerphil.com/parcelable-vs-serializable/

Comment: Serializable is too slow for large POJOs. Using a Bus is a much better pattern.

Comment: Why cant one just pass an object as is? Whats the point of serializing and then de-serializing in the other activity? Its not like you are parsing it between different languages or machines? Its From one class to another?

Comment: I think the accepted answer here is sufficient and more recommended in terms of performance compared to Serializable or Parcelable. In Android, encapsulation is not really important and encapsulation is really not advised in Android because of performance reasons. Just remember the gotchas of using static value that can lead to something unexpected depending on your use case.

Comment: So how come we can pass a String, which is technically an object, but not any other object type? iOS handles this functionality through a single variable assignment, why does Android have this prohibiting method of passing data?

Comment: Upvoted since this answer tells about a method recommended by Android. But If serializable (or parcelable) is the recommended solution, then it is like going back to write code in the 1970s. The OOPS concept is created around objects. If a list and detail screen cannot share the same object, then we may as well write code in caves. Terrible from Android

Comment: Terrible answer. With pseudocode. Just give the code. Psh

Answer (score 343):

Implement your class with Serializable. Let's suppose that this is your entity class:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

@SuppressWarnings("serial") //With this annotation we are going to hide compiler warnings
public class Deneme implements Serializable {

    public Deneme(double id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public double getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(double id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private double id;
    private String name;
}
```

We are sending the object called `dene` from X activity to Y activity. Somewhere in X activity;

```
Deneme dene = new Deneme(4,"Mustafa");
Intent i = new Intent(this, Y.class);
i.putExtra("sampleObject", dene);
startActivity(i);
```

In Y activity we are getting the object.

```
Intent i = getIntent();
Deneme dene = (Deneme)i.getSerializableExtra("sampleObject");
```

That's it.

Comment: It was really helpfull for me. Thanks... But when receiving the passed object, the syntax Should be [ Deneme dene = (Deneme)i.getSerializableExtra("sampleObject");
 ] ... Is it ???

Comment: @MustafaGüven But i am getting `classCastException: java.lang.Long` by doing so. Can you please explain why?

Comment: There is no any relation with my answer. It's very different thing you are getting. Could you share your codes?

Comment: Serializable is too slow for large POJOs. Using a Bus is a much better pattern.

Comment: Why should I have to prefix `(Serializable)` to the object?

Comment: simple. it's because of transmission. you have to look for the detailed explanation of serialization and its purpose in java (same in c#)

Comment: Just a side note, AFAIK in Android it's really not recommended to encapsulate class members with setters and getters because of a little bit of performance overhead. It's more advised to access them directly.

Comment: prefer this implementation parceable is so annoying to use and difference is not noticeable for small objects

Comment: Nice, works with implements Parceable as well.

Answer (score 166):

Use [gson](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to convert your object to JSON and pass it through intent. In the new Activity convert the JSON to an object.

In your `build.gradle`, add this to your dependencies

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.4'
```

In your Activity, convert the object to json-string:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String myJson = gson.toJson(vp);
intent.putExtra("myjson", myjson);
```

In your receiving Activity, convert the json-string back to the original object:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourObject ob = gson.fromJson(getIntent().getStringExtra("myjson"), YourObject.class);
```

For **Kotlin** it's quite the same

Pass the data

```
val gson = Gson()
val intent = Intent(this, YourActivity::class.java)
intent.putExtra("identifier", gson.toJson(your_object))
startActivity(intent)
```

Receive the data

```
val gson = Gson()
val yourObject = gson.fromJson<YourObject>(intent.getStringExtra("identifier"), YourObject::class.java)
```

Comment: Its an overkill , gson is just a type of string serialization to json , its better to implement Serializable or Paracable .

Comment: Theres no need to implement serializable in every object and in every project (waste of time) if you can use a library (gson) that handles that. And about overkill, theres dual and quadcore phones out there, they can handle even a list following this answer idea.

Comment: I would also recommend using gson because gson can also serialize arraylists in addition to above.

Comment: This is great! In my case, I am using a library that the objects do no implement serializable or parcelable. So this is my only option afaik

Comment: I have a problem with `Gson` --> here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39535222/problems-with-gson-library

Comment: This is the "best" option. Some classes are so simple, you don't need to over complicate their implementation by implementing serializable

Comment: IMHO, thinking **developer experience**, I go with this solution. I don't mind paying the minor cost of converting my simple `pojo` to `json` while keeping the representing class as simple as possible.

Comment: Isn't gson slower than serialize?

Comment: The Kotlin method is getString, not getStringExtra, but it won't let me edit the answer because edits have to be at least 6 characters

Comment: Gson is the cleanest way.  I started using Parcelable, but it's awful - way too much code needs to be added to the data classes.  The data classes shouldn't need to worry about passing objects around.

Comment: Out-of-the-box solution. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 133):

- Using global **static variables is not good software engineering** practice.
- **Converting an object's fields into primitive** data types can be **a hectic job**.
- Using **serializable is OK, but it's not performance-efficient** on the Android platform.
- **Parcelable is specifically** designed for Android and you should use it. Here is a simple example: *[Passing custom objects between Android activities](http://sohailaziz05.blogspot.com/2012/04/passing-custom-objects-between-android.html)*

You can generate Parcelable code for you class using this [site](http://www.parcelabler.com/).

Comment: What if my object contains nested Arraylist?

Comment: Well perhaps but one should really take ``performance'' with a grain of salt imo. If that comes at the price of implementing `Parcelable` then I'd rather keep my POJO classes Android-agnostic and use `Serializable`.

Comment: I don't agree that you should use Parcelable. A simple BUS pattern is much more efficient at runtime and saves a heck of a lot of dev time.

Comment: According to this benchmark https://bitbucket.org/afrishman/androidserializationtest Serializable is much faster than Parcelable. Please stop sharing this 5 year old nonsense about Parcelable.

Comment: As it stands, this answer is almost link-only. Can you add some example code or something into this answer itself?

Comment: How are global static variables "not good software engineering practice"? You can make something like a singleton cache and/or data grid then pass around ID's or similar. When you pass around references in Java you're using global static variables in a sense anyway as they point to the same object.

Comment: but , when implementing Parcelable interface ,and receiving through Receiver am getting RuntimeException .

Comment: @afrish dead link, see [archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20190201023958/https://bitbucket.org/afrishman/androidserializationtest) for results: *"3.6 times faster than Parcelable for writes and about 1.6 times faster for reads"*

Answer (score 100):

While calling an activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(fromClass.this,toClass.class).putExtra("myCustomerObj",customerObj);
```

In toClass.java receive the activity by

```
Customer customerObjInToClass = getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("myCustomerObj");
```

Please make sure that customer class implements parcelable

```
public class Customer implements Parcelable {

    private String firstName, lastName, address;
    int age;

    /* all your getter and setter methods */

    public Customer(Parcel in ) {
        readFromParcel( in );
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public LeadData createFromParcel(Parcel in ) {
            return new Customer( in );
        }

        public Customer[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Customer[size];
        }
    };


    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeString(firstName);
        dest.writeString(lastName);
        dest.writeString(address);
        dest.writeInt(age);
    }

    private void readFromParcel(Parcel in ) {

        firstName = in .readString();
        lastName  = in .readString();
        address   = in .readString();
        age       = in .readInt();
    }
```

Comment: Adhavan, I got a question. When you create the first Intent class, you pass in fromClass.this as the first argument. Is there a way to retrieve this object in the receiving activity class?

Comment: Miliu, fromClass fr = (fromClass) getParent(); is this what u needed?

Comment: Adhava, I actually did this, but fr is null. Any idea why?

Comment: miliu,please share your exception trace by that we can look into it.

Comment: Parcelable has a heck of a lot of unecessary boiler plate code and is quite frankly a waste of time. Rather use a Bus. See my post below.

Answer (score 92):

In my experience there are three main solutions, each with its disadvantages and advantages:

1. Implementing Parcelable
2. Implementing Serializable
3. Using a light-weight event bus library of some sort (for example, Greenrobot's EventBus or Square's Otto)

**[Parcelable](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable)** - fast and Android standard, but it has lots of boilerplate code and requires hard-coded strings for reference when pulling values out the intent (non-strongly typed).

**[Serializable](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable)** - close to zero boilerplate, but it is the slowest approach and also requires hard-coded strings when pulling values out the intent (non-strongly typed).

**[Event Bus](http://greenrobot.org/eventbus/documentation/how-to-get-started/)** - zero boilerplate, fastest approach, and does not require hard-coded strings, but it does require an additional dependency (although usually lightweight, ~40  KB)

I posted a very detailed comparison of these three approaches, including efficiency benchmarks.

Comment: Link to the article is dead. Still available on webarchive : https://web.archive.org/web/20160917213123/http://www.stevenmarkford.com/passing-objects-between-android-activities

Comment: It's a shame that the link is down :(

Comment: The problem of usage of Event Bus is when target Activity is recreated due to rotation for example. In this case target Activity has not access to passed object because this object was consumed from the bus by earlier call.

Comment: @JuliuszJ how does this differ to the other options? you always going to have to persist some sort of state in the target activity when it initially receives it no matter what approach. There is also the concept of a sticky bus message if you need.

Comment: I have taken the link to my blog away for now. Until I decide to re-instate my blog.

Comment: Parcelable is the fastest and with this generator (http://www.parcelabler.com/), you can paste your class and it can generate the code for you. Simple.

Comment: @ByWaleed ... I absolutely agree, I always use this site, makes stuff without any hassels. However, I have had a lot of unsuccessful tries, when I try to use a POJO that is composed of another Object. For some reason its out put doesnt really work.

Comment: @Yo Apps, I think you might be missing some small details which means it doesn't work. Look into the errors that you get and that can lead to where the issue is. Never the less, you cannot guarantee 100% compatibility with automated system like this and will have to use your programming intellect to find errors. Often, they are small but can also be due to not fully understand what you want to achieve or how to use the available tools to achieve that outcome.

Comment: I cannot use `Event Bus` when I create activity and want to pass, already created, object to it. `EventBus.getDefault().post` must be called when subscribers have already registered. I can suppose that I should start second activity and wait for it's creation and then call `EventBus.getDefault().post`

Answer (score 58):

I found a simple & elegant method:

- **NO Parcelable**
- **NO Serializable**
- **NO Static Field**
- **No Event Bus**

### Method 1

Code for the first activity:

```
    final Object objSent = new Object();
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBinder("object_value", new ObjectWrapperForBinder(objSent));
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class).putExtras(bundle));
    Log.d(TAG, "original object=" + objSent);
```

Code for the second activity:

```
    final Object objReceived = ((ObjectWrapperForBinder)getIntent().getExtras().getBinder("object_value")).getData();
    Log.d(TAG, "received object=" + objReceived);
```

you will find `objSent` & `objReceived` have the same `hashCode`, so they are identical.

But why can we pass a Java object in this way?

Actually, an Android binder will create a global [JNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Native_Interface) reference for a Java object and release this global JNI reference when there aren't any reference for this Java object. The binder will save this global JNI reference in the Binder object.

***Caution: this method *only* work unless the two activities run in the same process, otherwise throw ClassCastException at (ObjectWrapperForBinder)getIntent().getExtras().getBinder("object_value")***

Class ObjectWrapperForBinder definition:

```
public class ObjectWrapperForBinder extends Binder {

    private final Object mData;

    public ObjectWrapperForBinder(Object data) {
        mData = data;
    }

    public Object getData() {
        return mData;
    }
}
```

### Method 2

- for the sender,

  1. use custom native method to add your Java object to JNI global reference table(via JNIEnv::NewGlobalRef)
  2. put the return integer (actually, JNIEnv::NewGlobalRef return jobject, which is a pointer, we can cast it to int safely) to your Intent(via Intent::putExtra)
- for the receiver

  1. get integer from Intent(via Intent::getInt)
  2. use a custom native method to    restore your Java object from JNI global reference table (via JNIEnv::NewLocalRef)
  3. remove item from JNI global reference table(via
     JNIEnv::DeleteGlobalRef),

But Method 2 has a little, but serious issue, if the receiver fail to restore the Java object (for example, some exception happen before restore the Java object, or the receiver Activity does not exist at all), then the Java object will become an orphan or memory leak.
Method 1 don't have this issue, because android binder will handle this exception

##Method 3##

To invoke the Java object remotely, we will create a data contract/interface to describe the Java object. We will use the **.aidl* file:

IDataContract.aidl

```
package com.example.objectwrapper;
interface IDataContract {
    int func1(String arg1);
    int func2(String arg1);
}
```

Code for the first activity

```
    final IDataContract objSent = new IDataContract.Stub() {

        @Override
        public int func2(String arg1) throws RemoteException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "func2:: arg1=" + arg1);
            return 102;
        }

        @Override
        public int func1(String arg1) throws RemoteException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.d(TAG, "func1:: arg1=" + arg1);
            return 101;
        }
    };
    final Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putBinder("object_value", objSent.asBinder());
    startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class).putExtras(bundle));
    Log.d(TAG, "original object=" + objSent);
```

Code for the second activity:

Change the *android:process* attribute in file *AndroidManifest.xml* to a non-empty process name to make sure the second

```
    final IDataContract objReceived = IDataContract.Stub.asInterface(getIntent().getExtras().getBinder("object_value"));
    try {
        Log.d(TAG, "received object=" + objReceived + ", func1()=" + objReceived.func1("test1") + ", func2()=" + objReceived.func2("test2"));
    } catch (RemoteException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In this way, we can pass an interface between two activities, even though they run in a different process, and call the interface method remotely.

### Method 4

Method 3 seems not simple enough, because we must implement an *aidl* interface.
If you just want to do a simple task and the method return value is unnecessary, we can use *android.os.Messenger*.

Code for the first activity (sender):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    public static final int MSG_OP1 = 1;
    public static final int MSG_OP2 = 2;

    public static final String EXTRA_MESSENGER = "messenger";

    private final Handler mHandler = new Handler() {

        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e(TAG, "handleMessage:: msg=" + msg);
            switch (msg.what) {
            case MSG_OP1:

                break;
            case MSG_OP2:
                break;

            default:

                break;
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }

    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        startActivity(new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class).putExtra(EXTRA_MESSENGER, new Messenger(mHandler)));
    }
}
```

Code for the second activity (receiver):

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        final Messenger messenger = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MESSENGER);
        try {
            messenger.send(Message.obtain(null, MainActivity.MSG_OP1, 101, 1001, "10001"));
            messenger.send(Message.obtain(null, MainActivity.MSG_OP2, 102, 1002, "10002"));
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

All the *Messenger.send* will execute in a Handler asynchronously and sequentially.

Actually, *android.os.Messenger* is also an *aidl interface*. If you have the Android source code, you can find a file named *IMessenger.aidl*.

```
package android.os;

import android.os.Message;

/** @hide */
oneway interface IMessenger {
    void send(in Message msg);
}
```

Comment: Sorry I did not see that you had binding in your answer as well I feel that your answer is also very elegant.

Comment: Wow.... This man's 1st method is tremendous..... When you have very big/larger sized objects that works well

Comment: Thanks a lot for ObjectWrapperForBinder method, really helps!

Comment: This methods are really excellent: light and straightforward. I just had to check the API level on runtime as putBinder needs level 18. I have done it with something like (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) and it works like a charm. I am using method 1.

Answer (score 40):

You could also write the object's data into temporary Strings and ints, and pass them to the activity. Of course that way, you get the data transported, but not the object itself.

But if you just want to display them, and not use the object in another method or something like that, it should be enough. I did it the same way to just display data from one object in another activity.

```
String fName_temp   = yourObject.getFname();
String lName_temp   = yourObject.getLname();
String age_temp     = yourObject.getAge();
String address_temp = yourObject.getAddress();

Intent i = new Intent(this, ToClass.class);
i.putExtra("fname", fName_temp);
i.putExtra("lname", lName_temp);
i.putExtra("age", age_temp);
i.putExtra("address", address_temp);

startActivity(i);
```

You could also pass them in directly instead of the temp ivars, but this way it's clearer, in my opinion. Additionally, you can set the temp ivars to null so that they get cleaned by the GarbageCollector sooner.

Good luck!

On a side note: override toString() instead of writing your own print method.

As mentioned in the comments below, this is how you get your data back in another activity:

```
String fName = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("fname");
```

Comment: get your data back again with: String fName = getIntent().getExtras().getInt("fname");

Comment: To get the data back:

`Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();`

`String val = extras.getString("fname");`

Comment: This can quickly become infeasible for large POJOs. Rather use a Bus. See my post below.

Comment: as I mentioned in my answer, this is for simple usecases where you don't need the object itself, but rather just some values of it. It's not ment to be a soslution for complex usecases.

Comment: Good idea to pass a single object, but I'm trying to pass an array of unknown size of my object. Perhaps your solution is not for passing object arrays.

Comment: yeah the original question asked to pass one object to another activity, not an array. there are more efficient and better solutions for that.

Answer (score 31):

I made a singleton helper class that holds temporary objects.

```
public class IntentHelper {

    private static IntentHelper _instance;
    private Hashtable<String, Object> _hash;

    private IntentHelper() {
        _hash = new Hashtable<String, Object>();
    }

    private static IntentHelper getInstance() {
        if(_instance==null) {
            _instance = new IntentHelper();
        }
        return _instance;
    }

    public static void addObjectForKey(Object object, String key) {
        getInstance()._hash.put(key, object);
    }

    public static Object getObjectForKey(String key) {
        IntentHelper helper = getInstance();
        Object data = helper._hash.get(key);
        helper._hash.remove(key);
        helper = null;
        return data;
    }
}
```

Instead of putting your objects within Intent, use IntentHelper:

```
IntentHelper.addObjectForKey(obj, "key");
```

Inside your new Activity, you can get the object:

```
Object obj = (Object) IntentHelper.getObjectForKey("key");
```

Bear in mind that once loaded, the object is removed to avoid unnecessary references.

Comment: Good idea! Additionally may be you can create an additional class ObjectContainer { 
Object, obj; 
boolean permanent; ....}
Idea is that, you may pass a boolean in add method if you need to keep object persistant and don't remove when we call get. It will help keeping some global objects. Like may be an open bluetooth connection etc.

Comment: Cute but don't re-invent the wheel. Bus pattern is elegant and more powerful. See my post below.

Comment: @StevenMarkFord so does Bus pattern still holds true til this day? I am trying to improve a codebase with a code like this accessing data between activities: `BookActivity.getInstance().recommendationResponse` in `RoomsActivity`

Comment: When the receiving Activity is recreated (eg on screen rotation) `obj` becomes `null`. To avoid this, `obj` should be stored somewhere to get it again. Indeed the Json solution stores object data in Intent.

Answer (score 26):

There are a couple of ways by which you can access variables or objects in other classes or Activity.

A. Database

B. Shared preferences.

C. Object serialization.

D. A class which can hold common data can be named as Common Utilities. It depends on you.

E. Passing data through Intents and Parcelable Interface.

It depends upon your project needs.

A. **Database**

[SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) is an open source database which is embedded into Android. SQLite supports standard relational database features like SQL syntax, transactions and prepared statements.

[Tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html)

B. **Shared preferences**

Suppose you want to store username. So there will now be two things, a **key** username, **value** value.

**How to store**

```
 // Create object of SharedPreferences.
 SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

 //Now get Editor
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();

 //Put your value
 editor.putString("userName", "stackoverlow");

 //Commits your edits
 editor.commit();
```

*Using putString(), putBoolean(), putInt(), putFloat(), and putLong() you can save your desired dtatype.*

**How to fetch**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String userName = sharedPref.getString("userName", "Not Available");
```

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

C. **Object serialization**

Object serlization is used if we want to save an object state to send it over a network or you can use it for your purpose also.

Use Java beans and store in it as one of his fields and use getters and setter for that.

[JavaBeans](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans) are Java classes that have properties. Think of
properties as private instance variables. Since they're private, the only way
they can be accessed from outside of their class is through methods in the class. The methods that change a property's value are called setter methods, and the methods that retrieve a property's value are called getter methods.

```
public class VariableStorage implements Serializable  {

    private String inString;

    public String getInString() {
        return inString;
    }

    public void setInString(String inString) {
        this.inString = inString;
    }
}
```

Set the variable in your mail method by using

```
VariableStorage variableStorage = new VariableStorage();
variableStorage.setInString(inString);
```

Then use object serialzation to serialize this object and in your other class deserialize this object.

In serialization an object can be represented as a sequence of bytes that includes the object's data as well as information about the object's type and the types of data stored in the object.

After a serialized object has been written into a file, it can be read from the file and deserialized. That is, the type information and bytes that represent the object and its data can be used to recreate the object in memory.

If you want tutorial for this refer to:

- *[Serialization in Java](http://javawithswaranga.blogspot.in/2011/08/serialization-in-java.html)* (blog post)
- *[Get variable in other classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15999934/get-variable-in-other-classes/16000005#16000005)* (Stack Overflow)

D. **CommonUtilities**

You can make a class by yourself which can contain common data which you frequently need in your project.

**Sample**

```
public class CommonUtilities {

    public static String className = "CommonUtilities";

}
```

E. **Passing data through intents**

Please refer the tutorial *[Android – Parcel data to pass between Activities using Parcelable classes](http://shri.blog.kraya.co.uk/2010/04/26/android-parcel-data-to-pass-between-activities-using-parcelable-classes/)* for this option of passing data.

Answer (score 25):

Create your own class `Customer` as follows:

```
import import java.io.Serializable;
public class Customer implements Serializable
{
    private String name;
    private String city;

    public Customer()
    {
        
    }
    public Customer(String name, String city)
    {
        this.name= name;
        this.city=city;
    }
    public String getName() 
    {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) 
    {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public String getCity() 
    {
        return city;
    }
    public void setCity(String city) 
    {
        this.city= city;
    }
    
}
```

In your `onCreate()` method

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_top);
    
    Customer cust=new Customer();
    cust.setName("abc");
    cust.setCity("xyz");
    
    Intent intent=new Intent(abc.this,xyz.class);
    intent.putExtra("bundle",cust);
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

In `xyz activity` class you need to use the following code:

```
Intent intent=getIntent();
Customer cust=(Customer)intent.getSerializableExtra("bundle");
textViewName.setText(cust.getName());
textViewCity.setText(cust.getCity());
```

Comment: ..Check your code you are passing "bundle" as key for put cust obj & getting from "class" ..pls use one key either "class" or "bundle" ..

Comment: I face 
   Error:    Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object

Answer (score 16):

```
public class MyClass implements Serializable{
    Here is your instance variable
}
```

Now you want to pass the object of this class in startActivity. Simply use this:

```
Bundle b = new Bundle();
b.putSerializable("name", myClassObject);
intent.putExtras(b);
```

This works here because MyClass implements `Serializable`.

Comment: can you please explain or elaborate more

Comment: HomeworkData homeworkData = homeWorksList.get(position);   Intent intent = new Intent(c, HomeWorkActivitydetail.class);     Bundle b = new Bundle();
                b.putSerializable("CompleteData", homeworkData);

                intent.putExtras(b);
                c.startActivity(intent);
 at a time of object add gives me some error for adding object elements can we not pass complete object with this

Comment: inside of homeworkData i am having some values these are come to add

Answer (score 14):

The best way is to have a class (call it Control) in your application that will hold a static variable of type 'Customer' (in your case). Initialize the variable in your Activity A.

For example:

```
Control.Customer = CustomerClass;
```

Then go to Activity B and fetch it from Control class. Don't forget to assign a null after using the variable, otherwise memory will be wasted.

Comment: @aez Because it's sloppy from a design viewpoint and will break horribly if the Intent is ever in another process.

Comment: You will run into issues when resuming your app to Activity B. Since the Activity can be killed by Android and the object will not be saved.

Answer (score 12):

If you choose use the way Samuh describes, remember that only primitive values can be sent. That is, values that are parcable. So, if your object contains complex objects these will not follow. For example, variables like Bitmap, HashMap etc... These are tricky to pass by the intent.

In general I would advice you to send only primitive datatypes as extras, like String, int, boolean etc. In your case it would be: `String fname`, `String lname`, `int age`, and `String address`.

My opinion: More complex objects are better shared by implementing a **ContentProvider**, **SDCard**, etc. It's also possible to use a **static variable**, but this may fastly lead to error-prone code...

But again, it's just my subjective opinion.

Answer (score 8):

*I am using parcelable to send data from one activity to another acivity. Here is my code that works fine in my project.*

```
public class Channel implements Serializable, Parcelable {

    /**  */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 4861597073026532544L;

    private String cid;
    private String uniqueID;
    private String name;
    private String logo;
    private String thumb;


    /**
     * @return The cid
     */
    public String getCid() {
        return cid;
    }

    /**
     * @param cid
     *     The cid to set
     */
    public void setCid(String cid) {
        this.cid = cid;
    }

    /**
     * @return The uniqueID
     */
    public String getUniqueID() {
        return uniqueID;
    }

    /**
     * @param uniqueID
     *     The uniqueID to set
     */
    public void setUniqueID(String uniqueID) {
        this.uniqueID = uniqueID;
    }

    /**
     * @return The name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    /**
     * @param name
     *            The name to set
     */
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the logo
     */
    public String getLogo() {
        return logo;
    }

    /**
     * @param logo
     *     The logo to set
     */
    public void setLogo(String logo) {
        this.logo = logo;
    }

    /**
     * @return the thumb
     */
    public String getThumb() {
        return thumb;
    }

    /**
     * @param thumb
     *     The thumb to set
     */
    public void setThumb(String thumb) {
        this.thumb = thumb;
    }


    public Channel(Parcel in) {
        super();
        readFromParcel(in);
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<Channel> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Channel>() {
        public Channel createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Channel(in);
        }

        public Channel[] newArray(int size) {

            return new Channel[size];
        }
    };

    public void readFromParcel(Parcel in) {
        String[] result = new String[5];
        in.readStringArray(result);

        this.cid = result[0];
        this.uniqueID = result[1];
        this.name = result[2];
        this.logo = result[3];
        this.thumb = result[4];
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {

        dest.writeStringArray(new String[] { this.cid, this.uniqueID,
                this.name, this.logo, this.thumb});
    }
}
```

*In activityA use it like this:*

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelableArrayList("channel",(ArrayList<Channel>) channels);
Intent intent = new Intent(ActivityA.this,ActivityB.class);
intent.putExtras(bundle);
startActivity(intent);
```

*In ActivityB use it like this to get data:*

```
Bundle getBundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
List<Channel> channelsList = getBundle.getParcelableArrayList("channel");
```

Answer (score 7):

You can try to use that class. The limitation is that it can't be used outside of one process.

One activity:

```
 final Object obj1 = new Object();
 final Intent in = new Intent();
 in.putExtra(EXTRA_TEST, new Sharable(obj1));
```

Other activity:

```
final Sharable s = in.getExtras().getParcelable(EXTRA_TEST);
final Object obj2 = s.obj();

public final class Sharable implements Parcelable {

    private Object mObject;

    public static final Parcelable.Creator < Sharable > CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator < Sharable > () {
        public Sharable createFromParcel(Parcel in ) {
            return new Sharable( in );
        }


        @Override
        public Sharable[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Sharable[size];
        }
    };

    public Sharable(final Object obj) {
        mObject = obj;
    }

    public Sharable(Parcel in ) {
        readFromParcel( in );
    }

    Object obj() {
        return mObject;
    }


    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }


    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(final Parcel out, int flags) {
        final long val = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
        out.writeLong(val);
        put(val, mObject);
    }

    private void readFromParcel(final Parcel in ) {
        final long val = in .readLong();
        mObject = get(val);
    }

    /////

    private static final HashMap < Long, Object > sSharableMap = new HashMap < Long, Object > (3);

    synchronized private static void put(long key, final Object obj) {
        sSharableMap.put(key, obj);
    }

    synchronized private static Object get(long key) {
        return sSharableMap.remove(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

This question is also discussed in another Stack Overflow question. Please have a look at [a solution to *Passing data through intent using Serializable*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14333449/passing-data-through-intent-using-serializable/28673100#28673100). The main point is about using `Bundle` object which stores the necessary data inside `Intent`.

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

 bundle.putSerializable(key1, value1);
 bundle.putSerializable(key2, value2);
 bundle.putSerializable(key3, value3);

 intent.putExtras(bundle);
```

To extract values:

```
 Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

 for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
 value = bundle.getSerializable(key));
 }
```

Advantage of `Serializable` is its simplicity. However, you should consider using `Parcelable` method if you need many data to be transferred, because `Parcelable` is specifically designed for Android and it is more efficient than `Serializable`. You can create `Parcelable` class using:

1. an online tool - **[parcelabler](http://www.parcelabler.com/)**
2. a plugin for Android Studio - **[Android Parcelable code generator](http://corochann.com/fast-easy-parcelable-implementation-with-android-studio-parcelable-plugin-641.html)**

Answer (score 6):

Start another activity from this activity and pass parameters via Bundle Object

```
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("USER_NAME", "xyz@gmail.com");
startActivity(intent);
```

Retrieve data on another activity (YourActivity)

```
String s = getIntent().getStringExtra("USER_NAME");
```

This is ok for a simple kind of data type.
But if u want to pass complex data in between activities. U need to serialize it first.

Here we have Employee Model

```
class Employee{
    private String empId;
    private int age;
    print Double salary;
    
    getters...
    setters...
}
```

You can use Gson lib provided by google to serialize the complex data
like this

```
String strEmp = new Gson().toJson(emp);
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), YourActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("EMP", strEmp);
startActivity(intent);

Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
String empStr = bundle.getString("EMP");
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            Type type = new TypeToken<Employee>() {
            }.getType();
            Employee selectedEmp = gson.fromJson(empStr, type);
```

Answer (score 5):

Crete a class like bean class and implement the `Serializable` interface. Then we can pass it through the `intent` method, for example:

```
intent.putExtra("class", BeanClass);
```

Then get it from the other activity, for example:

```
BeanClass cb = intent.getSerializableExtra("class");
```

Answer (score 5):

Create two methods in your custom Class like this

```
public class Qabir {

    private int age;
    private String name;

    Qabir(){
    }

    Qabir(int age,String name){
        this.age=age; this.name=name;
    }   

    // method for sending object
    public String toJSON(){
        return "{age:" + age + ",name:\"" +name +"\"}";
    }

    // method for get back original object
    public void initilizeWithJSONString(String jsonString){

        JSONObject json;        
        try {
            json =new JSONObject(jsonString );
            age=json.getInt("age");
            name=json.getString("name");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }
}
```

Now in your sender Activity do like this

```
Qabir q= new Qabir(22,"KQ");    
Intent in=new Intent(this,SubActivity.class);
in.putExtra("obj", q.toJSON());
startActivity( in);
```

And in your receiver Activity

```
Qabir q =new Qabir();
q.initilizeWithJSONString(getIntent().getStringExtra("obj"));
```

Answer (score 3):

Android Activity objects can be destroyed and reconstituted. So, you will need to use another approach to look **them - or any object they create**!!! -  up. That is, you could pass as static class reference but then the object handle (Java calls these "references", as does SmallTalk; but they are not references in the sense of C or assembly) will be possibly invalid later because a "feature" of Android OE is any Activity can be annihilated and reconstituted later.

The original question asked "How to pass object from one activity to another in Android" and nobody has answered that. For sure, you can serialized (Serializable, Parcelable, to/from JSON) and pass a copy of the object's data and a new object having the same data could be created; but it will NOT have the same references/handles.  Also, many others mentioned you can store the reference in a static store. And that will work unless Android decides to onDestroy your Activity.

So, to really solve the original question you would need a static lookup plus each object will update its reference when/if it is recreated. E.g. each Android Activity would relist itself if its onCreate is called. You can also see how some people use the task list to search out an Activity by name. (system is temporarily destroying this instance of the activity to save space..getRunningTasks, the task list is effectively a specialized listing of the most recent object instance of each Activity).

For reference:

> Stopped:
> "The activity is completely obscured by another activity (the activity is now in the "background"). A stopped activity is also still alive (the **Activity object is retained in memory**, it maintains all state and member information, but is not attached to the window manager). However, it is no longer visible to the user and it can be killed by the system when memory is needed elsewhere."
>
> onDestroy
> "system is temporarily **destroying this instance** of the activity to save space."

So, the Message Bus is a workable solution. It basically "punts". Rather than try to have references to objects; then you re-architect your design to use MessagePassing instead of SequentialCode. Exponentially harder to debug; but it lets you ignore these sort of OperatingEnvironment understandings. Effectively, each object method access is inverted so the caller posts a Message and the object itself defines a handler for that message. Lots more code but can make it robust with the Android OE restrictions.

If all you want is the top Activity (typical thing in Android apps due to "Context" being needed everywhere), then you can just have each Activity lists itself as "top" in the static global space whenever its onResume is called. Then your AlertDialog or whatever which needs a context can just grab it from there. Also, its a bit yucky to use a global but can simplifying passing a Context up and down everywhere and, for sure, when you use a MessageBus then IT IS global anyways.

Comment: Otto has pro of being able to run it externally in just a a plain old Java app. So, good for dev and testing without having to mess with Android. Otto has con of big learning curve and most of what it solves is already solved in Android ways (local broadcast etc) or in normal app dev approaches ( you can write a much simpler global lookup than the global lookup of Otto, normal approaches are much more approachable for vectoring/F3 through code and for stepping through debugging).

Answer (score 2):

Yeah, using a static object is by far the easiest way of doing this with custom non-serialisable objects.

Comment: Yeah, I think I actually agree with you. Making those objects **`static`** is the better workaround if it's simply impractical to keep invoking `putExtra()` for every property you'd like to pass on. For example, right now, I want to pass an `ArrayList` that contains objects. I might as well make my ArrayList **`static`** instead.

Answer (score 2):

1. I know that static is bad, but it seems that we're forced to use it here. The problem with parceables/seriazables is that the two activities have duplicate instances of the same object = waste of memory and CPU.

   ```
   public class IntentMailBox {
       static Queue<Object> content = new LinkedList<Object>();
   }
   ```

---

Calling activity

```
IntentMailBox.content.add(level);
Intent intent = new Intent(LevelsActivity.this, LevelActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

---

Called activity (note that **onCreate()** and **onResume()** may be called multiple times when the system destroys and recreates activities)

```
if (IntentMailBox.content.size()>0)
    level = (Level) IntentMailBox.content.poll();
else
    // Here you reload what you have saved in onPause()
```

2. Another way is to declare a static field of the class that you want to pass in that very class. It will serve only for this purpose. Don't forget that it can be null in onCreate, because your app package has been unloaded from memory by system and reloaded later.
3. Bearing in mind that you still need to handle activity lifecycle, you may want to write all the data straight to shared preferences, painful with complex data structures as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Create your custom class like this:

```
public class Test implements Parcelable {
    String message;

    protected Test(Parcel in) {
        message = in.readString();
    }

    public static final Creator<Test> CREATOR = new Creator<Test>() {
        @Override
        public Test createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Test(in);
        }

        @Override
        public Test[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Test[size];
        }
    };

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(message);
    }
```

Send data using Intent like this:
Before starting your activity must set some data

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, PostDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("data", (Parcelable) test);
                ((context)).startActivity(intent);
```

Get data from intent like this:

```
Test test = (Test) getIntent().getParcelableExtra("data");
```

Comment: Please use `Parcelable`, it's about 10x faster to pass through process boundaries than Serializable.

Comment: Thank you for your support. I learn about it and upgrade it.

Answer (score 1):

The previous answers are almost all correct, but for those who don't understand those answers:

Android has a powerful class, **Intent**. With help of it, you share data between not only activity, but other components of Android (broadcast receiver, services for content provided we use ContetnResolver class no Intent).

In your activity you build intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context,SomeActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("key",value);
startActivity(intent);
```

In your receiving activity, you have

```
public class SomeActivity extends AppCompactActivity {

    public void onCreate(...){
    ...
          SomeObject someObject = getIntent().getExtras().getParceable("key");
    }
}
```

You have to implement Parceable or Serializable interface on your object in order to share between activities. It is hard to implement **Parcealbe** rather than the **Serializable** interface on the object. That's why android has plugins, especially for this. Download it and use it.

Answer (score 0):

I had always wondered why this can't be as simple as calling into a method of the other activity. I recently wrote a utility library that makes it almost as simple as that. You can check it out here(https://github.com/noxiouswinter/gnlib_android/wiki/gnlauncher).

**GNLauncher** makes sending objects/data to an Activity from another Activity etc as easy as calling a function in tha Activity with the required data as parameters. It introduces type safety and removes all the hastles of having to serialize, attaching to the intent using string keys and undoing the same at the other end.

## Usage

Define an interface with the methods you want to call on the Activity to launch.

```
public interface IPayload {
    public void sayHello(String name, int age);
}
```

Implement the above interface on the Activity to launch into.
Also notify GNLauncher when the activity is ready.

```
public class Activity_1 extends Activity implements IPayload {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //Notify GNLauncher when the Activity is ready. 
        GNLauncher.get().ping(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void sayHello(String name, int age) {
        Log.d("gnlib_test", "Hello " + name + "! \nYour age is: " + age);
    }
}
```

In the other Activity, get a proxy to the above Activity and call any method with the desired parameters.

```
public class Activity_2 extends Activity {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ((IPayload)GNLauncher.get().getProxy(this, IPayload.class, Activity_1.class)).sayHello(name, age);
    }
}
```

The first activity will be launched and the method called into with the required parameters.

## Prerequisites

Please refer to https://github.com/noxiouswinter/gnlib_android/wiki#prerequisites for information on how to add the dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Pass object from one activity to another activity.

(1) source activity

```
Intent ii = new Intent(examreport_select.this,
                    BarChartActivity.class);

            ii.putExtra("IntentExamResultDetail",
                    (Serializable) your List<ArraList<String>> object here);
            startActivity(ii);
```

(2) destination acitivity

```
List<ArrayList<String>> aa = (List<ArrayList<String>>) getIntent()
            .getSerializableExtra("IntentExamResultDetail");
```

Answer (score 0):

I used to set object with Pacelable or Serializable to transfer, but whenever I add other variables to object(model), I have to register it all. It's so nconvenient.

It's super easy to transfer object between activities or fragments.

[Android DataCache](http://github.com/kimkevin/AndroidDataCache)

Answer (score 0):

We can pass the object from one activity to another activity:

```
SupplierDetails poSuppliersDetails = new SupplierDetails();
```

Inside `poSuppliersDetails` we have some values. Now I am sending this object to target activity:

```
Intent iPODetails = new Intent(ActivityOne.this, ActivityTwo.class);
iPODetails.putExtra("poSuppliersDetails", poSuppliersDetails);
```

How to get this in ACtivityTwo:

```
private SupplierDetails supplierDetails;
    supplierDetails =(SupplierDetails) getIntent().getSerializableExtra("poSuppliersDetails");
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass one activity to another:

```
startActivity(new Intent(getBaseContext(),GetActivity.class).putExtra("passingkey","passingvalue"));
```

Get values:

```
String myvalue= getIntent().getExtras("passingkey");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to serialize all types of objects. For example, you can not serialize delegate methods or interfaces that carry code instead of data.
So I have written a 'Box' class you can use to pass any type of data **without serialization**.

##### 1. For putting data to intent use:

```
Intent I = new Intent(this, YourActivity.class);
CustomClass Date = new CustomClass();
Box.Add(I, "Name", Data);
```

##### 2. for retrieving data from an intent:**

```
CustomClass Data = Box.Get(getIntent(), "Name");
```

##### 3. for removing data after use, add this method to your activity:

```
@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    Box.Remove(getIntent());
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

##### 4. and add this code to your project:**

```
package ir.namirasoft.Utility;

import android.content.Intent;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Vector;

public class Box {
    // Number
    private static int Number = 1;

    public static int NextNumber() {
        return Number++;
    }

    //
    private static String _Intent_Identifier = "_Intent_Identifier";
    private static HashMap<Integer, Vector<Integer>> DeleteList = new HashMap<Integer, Vector<Integer>>();
    private static HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> ObjectList = new HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>>();

    public static int GetIntent_Identifier(Intent I) {
        int Intent_Identifier = I.getIntExtra(_Intent_Identifier, 0);
        if (Intent_Identifier == 0)
            I.putExtra(_Intent_Identifier, Intent_Identifier = NextNumber());
        return Intent_Identifier;
    }

    public static void Add(Intent I, String Name, Object O) {
        int Intent_Identifier = GetIntent_Identifier(I);
        synchronized (ObjectList) {
            if (!ObjectList.containsKey(Intent_Identifier))
                ObjectList.put(Intent_Identifier, new HashMap<String, Object>());
            ObjectList.get(Intent_Identifier).put(Name, O);
        }
    }

    public static <T> T Get(Intent I, String Name) {
        int Intent_Identifier = GetIntent_Identifier(I);
        synchronized (DeleteList) {
            DeleteList.remove(Intent_Identifier);
        }
        return (T) ObjectList.get(Intent_Identifier).get(Name);
    }

    public static void Remove(final Intent I) {
        final int Intent_Identifier = GetIntent_Identifier(I);
        final int ThreadID = NextNumber();
        synchronized (DeleteList) {
            if (!DeleteList.containsKey(Intent_Identifier))
                DeleteList.put(Intent_Identifier, new Vector<Integer>());
            DeleteList.get(Intent_Identifier).add(ThreadID);
        }
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60 * 1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                synchronized (DeleteList) {
                    if (DeleteList.containsKey(Intent_Identifier))
                        if (DeleteList.get(Intent_Identifier).contains(ThreadID))
                            synchronized (ObjectList) {
                                ObjectList.remove(Intent_Identifier);
                            }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
}
```

** The box class is threadsafe.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a library called [intentparser](https://github.com/lau1944/intentparser).

It's really easy to use.
Add this to your project Gradle file:

```kotlin
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
```

Add this to your application Gradle file:

```kotlin
dependencies {
            implementation 'com.github.lau1944:intentparser:v$currentVersion'
    }
```

Pass an object using the extension method *putObject*:

```kotlin
val testModel = TestModel(
            text = "hello world",
            isSuccess = false,
            testNum = 1,
            textModelSec = TextModelSec("second model")
)
startActivity(
     Intent(this, ActivityTest::class.java).apply {
          this.putObject(testModel)
     }
)
```

Get the object from the *previous activity*:

```kotlin
val testModel = intent.getObject(TestModel::class.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to pass an object from one activity to another activity in Android. But none of them has a direct option to simply pass the object via Intents or Bundles. All you need to do is **Decode** the Object, **Pass** as a Strings, **Encode** in NextActivity. The example is given below:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, nextActivity.class);
i.putExtra("fname", customer.getFirstName());
i.putExtra("lname", customer.getLastName());
i.putExtra("address", customer.getAddress());
startActivity(i);
```

The second method is quite simple. Use a **Static Object** that can be accessed from all activities easily.

Thirdly, last but not least, you can store the Object into some **Constant Java File** and then read that Object values from any activity.

Answer (score -1):

I see a lot of good options, but I was wondering why Binding hasn't been used.

> Passing a reference to an object just seems more efficient to me than serializing and desterilizing objects, but I have not done a deep dive to see if that is what is going on behind the scenes.

Creating a Binder is simple enough...

```
public class MyBinder extends Binder {

    private Object myObject;

    public MyBinder(Object object) {
        myObject = object;
    }

    public Object getObject() {
        return myObject;
    }

}
```

And creating the parcelable to use it isn't that bad either.

```
public class MyParcelable implements Parcelable {

    private Object myObject;

    public MyParcelable() {
    }

    public MyParcelable(Parcel parcel) {
        myObject = ((MyBinder)parcel.readStrongBinder()).getObject();
    }

    public void setObject(Object object) {
        myObject = object;
    }

    public Object getObject() {
        return myObject;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int flags) {
        parcel.writeStrongBinder(new MyBinder(myObject));
    }

    public int describeContents() {
        return myObject == null ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<MyParcelable>() {

        public MyParcelable createFromParcel(Parcel parcel) {
            return new MyParcelable(parcel);
        }

        public MyParcelable[] newArray(int length) {
            return new MyParcelable[length];
        }

    };
}
```

This logic is really cool because you are actually passing a reference from activity to activity.

> I would advise checking for nulls and if the instanceof Binder is MyBinder!

and to implement this you just...

Send it off

```
Object myObject = "some object";
MyParcelable myParcelable = new MyParcelable();
myParcelable.setObject(myObject);

intent.putExtra("MyParcelable", myParcelable);
```

Get it back

```
myParcelable = (MyParcelable) getIntent().getExtras().getParcelable("MyParcelable");
myObject = myParcelable.getObject();
```

Heck, someone could get all crazy and make this sucker a true generic.

Answer (score -22):

As mentioned in the comments, this answer breaks encapsulation and [tightly couples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) components, which is very likely not what you want. The best solution is probably making your object Parcelable or Serializable, as other responses explain. Having said that, the solution solves the problem. So if you know what you are doing:

Use a class with static fields:

```
public class Globals {
    public static Customer customer = new Customer();
}
```

Inside the activities you can use:

Activity From:

```
Globals.customer = myCustomerFromActivity;
```

Activity Target:

```
myCustomerTo = Globals.customer;
```

It's an easy way to pass information for activities.

Comment: I think this is an atrocious answer which totally breaks encapsulation, and tightly couples components. The correct solution is to use parcelable as stated in one of the answers lower down. This is horrible practice!!

Comment: Sometimes encapsulation is important and sometimes things are already tightly coupled so it really makes little difference.  Idealism *alone* is not worth hours of extra coding (plus more maintenance down the road).  Just recognize the limitations and possible problems from doing things this away and then decide if more effort up-front to be "proper" is worthwhile in the long run.

Comment: That's how it should look like: one statement to put, one statement to get, not dozens of lines of boilerplate error-prone code.

Comment: This can cause issues with using the back button. Using the above example,  say you have customerDetails activity. If at any point you allow the switching between customers, then that global value will be overwritten so going back via the back button will not always work as intended.

Comment: If the user is using Target Activity, then changes to another Application (opening notifications, or selecting an image from gallery app), may be possible that the current activity gets Distroyed. When the user gets back, you will get a null pointer Exception because this value was initialised in the previous activity.

Comment: There are millions of successful commercial projects which does not follow idealism completely, and +1 to Brian White for putting it in the correct way. When the crunch time approaches I'm pretty sure a shorter development time is preferred than a tiny degradation in performance.

Comment: This is a hack. Sometimes we have to hack code, but not when there are other better ways of doing it.